# how to log http request message(not body) and response message(not body) in asp.net core(Kestrel)

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

Sample of my request

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/values HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/6.4.1
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:5000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

and the response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2018 07:18:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 19

["value1","value2"]
```

i want get that all http message for log

how am I supposed to get request message and response message

because log that i can find any error(like error request message(custom TCP))

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to create custom Middleware where you can then inspect the request/response to build up the logs you need.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#writing-middleware

Middleware allows you to grab the request on the way in and the response on the way out.

On the context (HttpContext) you should be able to get the data you expect - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: thanks but request/response and HttpContext not Original Data。i want get Data in webService(Kestrel) Before processing。because log that i can find any error(like error request message(custom TCP)) –

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a middleware to log a (nearly) access log in the nginx style. 
You could do roughly the same and add and populate your own fields in the `LogData` class, and then change the `DefaultFormatter` function.

```
public class RequestLogMiddleware
{

    public class LogData {
        public IPAddress RemoteAddr {get;set;}
        public string User {get; set;}
        public int ResponseStatus {get; set;}

        public string RequestMethod {get;set;}
        public string RequestTimestamp {get;set;}
        public string RequestPath {get;set;}

        public string RequestProtocol {get;set;}
        public string UserAgent {get;set;}

        public long DurationMs {get;set;}
    }

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RequestLogMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = factory.CreateLogger("RequestLog");

    }

    private Func<LogData, string> _logLineFormatter;
    private Func<LogData,string> logLineFormatter{
        get  {

            if (this._logLineFormatter != null) {
                return this._logLineFormatter;
            } 
            return this.DefaultFormatter();
        }
        set {
            this._logLineFormatter = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override this to set the default formatter if none was supplied
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected Func<LogData, string> DefaultFormatter() {
            return (logData => $"{logData.RemoteAddr} - {logData.User} {logData.RequestTimestamp} \"{logData.RequestMethod} {logData.RequestPath} {logData.RequestProtocol}\" {logData.ResponseStatus} \"{logData.UserAgent}\" {logData.DurationMs}ms");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to set a custom formatter for this instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="formatter"></param>
    public void SetLogLineFormat(Func<LogData, string> formatter) {
        this._logLineFormatter = formatter;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await _next.Invoke(context);
        watch.Stop();

        var nowString = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffzzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        var user = context.User.Identity.Name ?? "-";
        var request = context.Request.Path +  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString.ToString()) ? "" : context.Request.QueryString.ToString());
        var responseStatus = context.Response.StatusCode;
        var userAgent = context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("User-Agent") ? context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString() : "-";
        var protocol = context.Request.Protocol;
        var duration = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        var remoteAddr = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;    
        var method = context.Request.Method;

        var logData = new LogData {
            RemoteAddr = remoteAddr,
            RequestMethod = method,
            RequestPath = request,
            RequestProtocol = protocol,
            RequestTimestamp = nowString,
            ResponseStatus = responseStatus,
            User = user,
            UserAgent = userAgent,
            DurationMs = duration,
        };

        _logger.LogInformation(this.logLineFormatter(logData));

    }
}
```

Just wire it up in the `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(RequestLogMiddleware));
```

Make sure it's the first middleware you add.

Example output:

```
info: RequestLog[0]
      ::1 - - 2018-08-10T14:23:04.183+02:00 "GET /api/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" 266ms
info: RequestLog[0]
      ::1 - - 2018-08-10T14:23:04.569+02:00 "POST /api/search HTTP/1.1" 401 "-" 31ms
info: RequestLog[0]
      ::1 - - 2018-08-10T14:23:04.375+02:00 "POST /api/search HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" 3453ms
info: RequestLog[0]
      ::1 - - 2018-08-10T14:23:04.375+02:00 "POST /api/search HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" 4341ms
info: RequestLog[0]
      ::1 - - 2018-08-10T14:23:08.932+02:00 "POST /api/search HTTP/1.1" 400 "-" 16ms
```

The logger can be turned on/off in configuration:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "RequestLog": "Information"
    }
},
```